# What are practical uses of the client-server mode?

Tags: clientserver

I know that Vim allows a client server mode ([`:h clientserver`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/remote.html#clientserver)): it is possible to turn it into a server which will get some commands and execute them and as a client which will send the commands to the server.

I get how it works, but I can't imagine a practical use of this feature: in which cases is it useful, and what workflow can be created using this feature?

So my question is simple: **What is the use of the client server mode of Vim?**

(I point out again that my question is not about how to make it work or how it works but why use it.)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/225004/using-vim-as-external-editor-using-only-one-instance, http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5354/205

Comment: I'm inclined to close this as too broad.

Comment: I would understand the closing as too broad. SE maybe isn't the most adapted platform to this question but I feel like I'm missing something about this feature so I thought other could benefit of these answers.

Answer (score 25):

- Before the channel/job recent feature of Vim 7.4, the client-server feature was the only way to do a decent background compilation -- without any dependency to Python. We start compilation as a background job, and when it finishes, it notifies back to vim, thanks to the client-server channel, that it has finished.
- It's also indirectly used by "plugins" like pyclewn to integrate a debugger into vim. Actually pyclewn uses the +netbeans feature (that is built on top of +clientserver). Other notable projects use this netbeans interface to integrate vim with an IDE -- see `:h netbeans-intro`.
- It's also used by some tests plugins like vimrunner to run tests in Vim from the command line. I use it to tests my plugins on travis.
- I also remember synchronizing my clicks in xdvi interface to my LaTeX source code thanks to +clientserver.

Comment: So it is useful not to be used by the user directly but by third party application. Thanks for your answer that is pretty interesting.

Comment: @statox Yes. That's the main use cases I see: simple integration with external tools. Simple because we can feed vim commands and functions  through the command line.

Comment: Eclim is another example of this.

Answer (score 18):

My use of this is a little more simplistic (and perhaps commonplace) than Luc Hermitte's.

If you start an instance of *gvim* with this compiled in (and it is, and has been for a long time, on, e.g., major linux distros like Fedora and Debian), it starts in server mode. I emphasized "gvim" because what I'm about to describe does not seem to apply to a singular `vim` instance in a GUI terminal (although I suppose it could be if you use the paramater appropriately).

Anyway, you can then open any file from anywhere in that gvim instance with `gvim --remote [file path]` (with no `--servername` specified).  I'm a fan of this because I don't navigate the filesystem much directly with vim; instead I use an [orthodox file browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_manager#Orthodox_file_managers) (midnight commander) -- or rather, piles of them open to different locations since `mc` is lightweight and allows for various color scheme skins to simplify differentiating between them (so I tend to have two or three open in separate tabs in at least one GUI terminal).  However, I think the same principle will apply to any file browser which allows you some form of customized hotkey you can associate with `gvim --remote %f`.  In `mc` I have it in the user menu, so F2 + e and the highlighted/selected file is sent to the gvim instance.

This gets a little better: If you open a *second* gvim instance, say, on monitor #2 of the same desktop, or a separate desktop, and perhaps a different colorscheme in that one, and this time give it an explicit `--servername foo`, you can send files to that instance instead with:

```
 gvim --servername foo --remote [file path]
```

Something which may or may not come in handy depending on the scope of what you are doing, etc.

Comment: That's a use case I hadn't envisaged but indeed if you don't like to navigate through your files from Vim that can be a good workaround.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't consider it a "work around" since the other thing I'm doing, minimally, with the file browser at the same time is glancing at files in the same locations (for text via `less`, which is instantaneous and one key to exit) and possibly sending them to applications other than vim that also have a remote mode like this (many things do now, including other "editors" which I sometimes use to leave stacked tabs of headers for viewing, and also web browsers).  Put another way, I'd say navigating the fs with vim seems like a work around for not using `mc` and `--remote`, ;)

Comment: Yup that's a workflow in itself and not a workaround, my phrasing wasn't ideal but I understood the idea of your answer ;-)

Comment: When working with Visual Studio, I do most of my editing in Vim. I use this feature to open the current file (with the cursor in the same location) at a keystroke. See the **Vim as an external tool** section on the [Integrate gvim with Visual Studio](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Integrate_gvim_with_Visual_Studio) Vim Tips page for how to set this up.

Comment: For those interested, I have discussed in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/588202 how to apply the same idea for a singular Vim instance in a GUI terminal instead of Gvim.

Answer (score 5):

Embedded development. A lot of times in embedded development you have a IP socket, but limited local hard drive space, or no non-volatile memory, or any number of other things. You can start a server on the embedded board, and then client into it on your development computer and have all your configuration and tags setup locally.

Comment: 5 years later and I would LOVE to know how to do this. In my case, I want to run vim in server mode within a Docker container, and client into that vim server from my Docker host (i.e my laptop). I can't find anything useful about what ports, etc. the server starts up on in `:h server`

Answer (score 3):

I wrote my masters thesis using Vim, LaTeX and BibTeX.  To manage my BibTeX references, I used a program called [JabRef](http://www.jabref.org/).  JabRef has a neat little feature where you can connect it to a Vim server instance, and then you can "push" the BibTeX reference from JabRef to the LaTeX document that you are editing in Vim.

Answer (score 2):

My workflow is similar to what *goldilocks* said in his answer. I use vim8's `:terminal` feature in combination with `--remote` option. I maintain 2 window layout in vim. Code in left window and terminal on the right. I use the right window(terminal) to run compilations, navigate file system and open files in current vim instance(from the terminal). This flow allows me to operate with very less mouse involvement.

I use gvim and icewm(any window manager should do)

Start a gvim instance

```
gvim somefile
```

Inside gvim, open terminal in vertical split

```
:botright vertical terminal
(or) short form
:bo vert term 
"botright" splits the window to right
```

In the terminal window split

```
gvim --remote-send '<C-w><C-w>' --remote anotherfile

"--remote-send" will send Ctrl-W Ctrl-W to remote gvim instance(in our case, current instance) 
to put the cursor in the left window. Otherwise, the terminal split would be replaced by
'anotherfile' buffer.
"--remote" will open 'anotherfile' in left window.
```

You can create aliases to these long commands in your .zshrc/.bashrc and shorten them to your liking.

With this workflow, I rarely move out of my gvim instance and rarely use the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

My common use case is to [open files in vim from a debugger](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Integrate_gvim_with_Visual_Studio) (Visual Studio, Xcode, etc). I want all the files to open in the same vim window, so I run it as a server and use `--remote` commands to open the files and jump at the right line and column (with `+"call cursor()"`).