# clientserver with sockets in regular Vim?

Tags: neovim, netrw, clientserver, network

I read [somewhere](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7972/1065) that you can use a socket do clientserver functionality but I can't figure out where the socket is.

Is it a file socket in the file system like mysql used to use?

Is it a tcp socket?

I don't see it mentioned anywhere in the remote.txt help file.

The reason I ask is that I'm using WSL2 and I can't seem to get a list of servers with `vim --serverlist` even though I have a Vim server running.

Comment: Does it maybe involve `netrw-` ?

Comment: It seems like `nvim` has the ability to do this, but requires an API be used to drive.

Comment: Do you have still something open in your question? How can we help you further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `--serverlist` functionality to work you need to have a version of Vim compiled with the `clientserver` functionality.

You can check if your version has been compiled with that functionality using the Vim command: `:version`

Remark: I have installed `WSL2` with the default Ubuntu distribution and the `clientserver` functionality is not present. I fear you have the same problem.

With this you could:

- Start Vim as a server with the following bash command:

```
vim --servername "VIM"
```

- Query the server name associated to an instance (e.g. `VIM` or `VIM1` or `GVIM`) with the following Vim command:

```
:echo v:servername
```

- Send some keys to another instance with the following bash command:

```
vim --servername "VIM" --remote-send "iHello World!<Esc>"
```

Comment: But I have the Gtk3 version installed and it has `+clientserver`; I checked:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378830/how-to-install-vim-with-clientserver-feature-enabled-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Maybe you could try the experiment I propose in my answer and let us know what are the intermediate result (I noticed that `vim --server-list` show me the list of server only for 1 second)

Comment: I noticed that on Linux if no server name is given the server is not started. I have adapted the answer accordingly.