# How to recover unsaved text without a swap file after Vim crashed?

Tags: microsoft-windows, swap-file, linux-ubuntu, crash-recovery

I am using Vim 8 in WSL Ubuntu. While copying text into a file the terminal crashed. I don't believe it is the WSL as Task Manager does not show 'Not Responding'.

I have tried using [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5354/how-do-i-close-vim-externally/5500#5500) which works on new terminals but not on the one that crashed, where it simply does nothing.

I can see the unsaved text on the unresponsive terminal running Vim and the `vim -r` command tells me `process ID: 1062 (still running)` but when opened with the read only option the unsaved text is not there.

Is there a way to recover this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was with WSL after all. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58130873/9506872) and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> this made the terminal responsive again allowing me to save my file. Also here to add, fullscreen On Off shortcut F11 will always fix crash.