# Run command on kill signal?

Tags: autocmd

Is there an autocmd event for kill signals (for e.g. [SIGTERM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully)) ? As [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25838/33130) answer indicates Vim can catch `SigUSR1` event. My use case is to save session on SIGTERM before quitting.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing like "kill signal". There are different signals application may receive from OS.

*SIGKILL* cannot be caught by any application. Never.

*SIGUSR1* can be processed by auto-command (see `:h SigUSR1` in Vim and `:h Signal` in Neovim).

*SIGINT* is caught and processed by Vim application. If it happens to run some script while *SIGINT* is being raised then that script can `:catch /^Vim:Interrupt$/` inside "try"-block.

*SIGHUP*, *SIGTERM* and alike force Vim to quit.

Comment: It is possible to catch SIGTERM as shown by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully) example in python. Does Vim allow doing something similar?

Comment: @tejasvi88 As I said, Vim simply quits upon SIGTERM.

Answer (score 1):

vim offers the autocmd `VimLeavePre`

```
:autocmd VimLeavePre * call CleanupStuff()
```

Although this is not technically specific to SIGTERM, it can be used in this sitaution.  You can use the variable `v:dying` to distinguish normal exits from abnormal (e.g., with a signal).